# Find elements on top of an element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a button that, when clicked, isn't receiving the "clicked" event, meaning *something* is hovering it. It might be some padding, some transparent div or anything else.

Is there a way I can check *what* is on top of that button?

Something like Firefox's 3D

[image]

Btw, the button isn't receiving the event only on low resolution devices (or making my Chrome window small), but works just fine in I make it wider.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the button to see what is on top of it?

Comment: Right-click > Inspect element, see what turns up in the DOM inspector.

Comment: @BrianRay Yes, of course. I can't see anything that could be on top of it, but the button is nested really deep in the DOM, so it could be any div a few dozens of DOM levels up.

Comment: No matter where it is in the DOM, the element on top will be highlighted when trying to inspect the button. Since it isn't, I believe that the issue has nothing to do with your CSS or layout.

Comment: The 3D view of FF is mostly a gimmick. It isn't showing you anything you can't already figure out easily by just looking at the existing DOM tree. If there is a child node, FF just adds a new box. All the way until there are no children. Really, it has little-to-no additional value in debugging other than "looks pretty".